# appending to python lists

Tags: python, list

I have a web **scraper** that returns me values like the example below.

```
# Other code above here.
test = []

results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.result_content")
for result in results:
    # Other code about result.find_element_by_blah_blah
    product_feature = result.find_element_by_class_name("prod-feature-icon")

    for each_item in product_feature.find_elements_by_tag_name('img'):
        zz = test.append(each_item.get_attribute('src')[34:-4])  # returning the values I want
        print(zz)
```

The code above would print out the results like this: (Which is the values I want)

```
TCP_active
CI
DOH_active
TCP_active
CI
DOH
TCP
CI_active
DOH_active
```

I want to achieve the results below:

```
[TCP_active, CI, DOH_active]
[TCP_active, CI, DOH]
[TCP, CI_active, DOH_active]
```

how should I be doing it?

I tried:

```
test.append(each_item.get_attribute('src')[34:-4])
```

But this gives me:

```
[TCP_active]
[TCP_active, CI]
[TCP_active, CI, DOH_active]
[TCP_active, CI, DOH_active, TCP]
...
```

Hope my explanation is clear

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand fully, but have you looked at using a dictionary for this?  It seems a dictionary would be a better and more elegant solution...

Comment: Amended my question which might be more helpful

Comment: Create a new list for each `result in results` iteration that `for each_item in product_feature.find_elements_by_tag_name(..)` loop appends to. Then append that list to `test`.

Comment: Was going to post an answer but @MartijnPieters has the right idea so I'll give him a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `print`, append your results to lists; one new list per iteration of the outer loop:

```
test = []

results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.result_content")
for result in results:
    # Other code about result.find_element_by_blah_blah
    product_feature = result.find_element_by_class_name("prod-feature-icon")
    features = [] 
    for each_item in product_feature.find_elements_by_tag_name('img'):
        features.append(each_item.get_attribute('src')[34:-4])
    test.append(features)
```

You can print `features` if you want to, or `test`, just to see what is happening at each level of your `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried your method, and it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, not exactly sure what you want, but the code below will give the output you want:

```
test = []

results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.result_content")
for result in results:
    # Other code about result.find_element_by_blah_blah
    product_feature = result.find_element_by_class_name("prod-feature-icon")

    zz = []
    for each_item in product_feature.find_elements_by_tag_name('img'):
        zz = test.append(each_item.get_attribute('src')[34:-4])  # returning the values I want

    print(zz)
```

If you want to store the data and not print it, use a dictionary something like this:

```
test = []
zz_store = {}

results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.result_content")
for result in results:
    # Other code about result.find_element_by_blah_blah
    product_feature = result.find_element_by_class_name("prod-feature-icon")

    zz = []
    for each_item in product_feature.find_elements_by_tag_name('img'):
        zz = test.append(each_item.get_attribute('src')[34:-4])  # returning the values I want

    zz_store[result] = zz
    print(zz)
```